# Compare classes between a table and a div and style those that do not appear

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure how to accomplish this , novice user here. I have a table , where i need to get all the classes from the "th". Then compare those classes to a div using the some of same classes. If the class name does not exist in the table , i want to display none on those ones in the divs. I haven't tried anything yet because i don't even know where to start.

Existing HTML - need to find all "th" class names.

```
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th class="class1">
   <th class="class2">
   <th class="class3">
   <th class="class4">
   <th class="class5">
   <th class="class6">
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Existing Div - i need to find all classes that have no matches found in the table above and display:none to them.

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="class1"></div>
 <div class="hide"></div>
 <div class="class2"></div>
 <div class="class3"></div>
 <div class="change"></div>
 <div class="class4"></div>
 <div class="class5"></div>
 <div class="class6"></div>
 <div class="help"></div>
</div>
```

The resulting HTML would look like this afterwards

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
  <div class="class1"></div>
  <div class="hide" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="class2"></div>
  <div class="class3"></div>
  <div class="change" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="class4"></div>
  <div class="class5"></div>
   <div class="class6"></div>
  <div class="help" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the implementation I have below. I have used an [iffe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to get immediate execution. So The code gets all `th` elements and for each of these elements, get its class and add it to the `classes` array. Next, you get all the `div` under `.wrapper` class and check if the class name matches the names in `classes` array.If that condition is not satisfied then modify the `display` attribute to `none`

```js
(function() {
  let classes = [];
  $('th').each(function() {
    classes.push($(this).attr("class"))
  })
  console.log(classes);

  $('.wrapper div').each(function() {
    let divClassName = $(this).attr("class");
    if (classes.indexOf(divClassName) == -1) {
      $(this).css('display', 'none')
    }
  })
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="class1">
        <th class="class2">
          <th class="class3">
            <th class="class4">
              <th class="class5">
                <th class="class6">
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="class1">class1</div>
  <div class="hide">hide</div>
  <div class="class2">class2</div>
  <div class="class3">class3</div>
  <div class="change">hide</div>
  <div class="class4">class4</div>
  <div class="class5">class5</div>
  <div class="class6">class6</div>
  <div class="help">hide</div>
</div>
```